# increase vector resolution in R

Tags: r, vector, plot

I am trying to figure out a method to increase the number of elements of vectors, in order to remove the angular effect visible when I plot the values of these vectors. For instance, let's say I got two vectors containing 10 elements each:

```
a = c(4,2,10,5,3,4,8,9,6,2)
b = seq(0,4.5, by=0.5)
```

They are subject to data smoothing, but I would like to increase their "resolution" to obtain more prediction points than 10 (its length). So, in other words, take the vector *a* and double (for example) its number of elements, while keeping its consistency. The resulting vector should be something like:

```
a = c(4,3,2,6,10,7,5,4,3,4,6,8,8.5,9,7.5,6,4,2,2)
```

Of course, in this particular case, I can easily compute the average of the elements pair-wise. But I would like to have a generalized method for an arbitrary length. I have tried with:

```
seq(a[1],a[10], length.out=20)
```

but of course this does not do the job as only the first and last element of the vector are taken in consideration. It is suitable for the second vector *b* though (which contains the abscissa values).
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Marius.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you consider "keeping its consistency" to mean? Just fit within the min and max values of a?

Comment: You may like either `splinefun` or `approxfun`

Comment: No, to get any two consecutive elements of vector *a* and add between them another 2 or 3 or..whatever elements that are evenly distributed, but respect the trend of the vector. For instance if initially a[5]=4 and a[6]=7 and a[7]=5, and I add another 2 elements between a[5] and a[6] and between a[6] and a[7] that piece of a vector should be a1[5]=4; a1[6]=5, a1[7]=6, a1[8]=7, a1[9]=6.34, a1[10]=5.68, a1[11]=5 with the initial a[5]=a1[5], a[6]=a1[8] and a[7]=a1[11]

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have created a spline function also, but I would like to increase the number of predicted values so the resulting line defining the trend of the data points (i.e., my vector elements) is not that angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want linear interpolation based on the `b` sequence?

```
 f <- approxfun(b, a)
 f(seq(b[1], b[length(b)], length = 20))
 [1] 4.000000 3.052632 2.105263 5.368421 9.157895 8.157895 5.789474 4.368421 3.421053 3.263158 3.736842 4.842105 6.736842 8.157895 8.631579 8.684211 7.263158 5.789474
 [19] 3.894737 2.000000
```

See `?approx` for other options and its `See also` for other forms of interpolation, also `?round` for rounding out the values in various ways.

Comment: No, I already obtained a linear interpolation using the seq() function, but most of my data describes a quadratic curve, that's why I specified that I would like to keep the consistency of the vector. But I will take a look at the approx and round.

Comment: You might be surprised how nicely approxfun or splinefun match your data just with default settings, especially if you increase the number of points - not sure what else you mean by "consistency".

Comment: From what I see the approxfun does the deal. Thank you for your quick reply. I have used also splinefun, but I needed a custom behavior for a spline function that is why I have created my own. Again, approxfun produces the wanted results. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, I claim first authorship of `approxfun` and will be suing mdsumner for plagiarism, copyright infringement, and theft of IP.   (This is parody, for those otten-ray ownvoters-day out there)